# How to add insert into a table from select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to insert data into one table, from selected data from another.  For example, I'm doing this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, Country FROM Suppliers;
```

For example,

It the select statement would return, and insert:

```
Robert    USA
Richard   Germany
Pat       USA
```

This works fine.

What i'm looking to do now, is populate a datetransfered column that is not part of the suppliers table.  The date will just be today (getdate)

The insert statement would be:

```
insert into Customer(CustomerName, Country, datetransfered)
```

How would I add the 'datetransfered' portion as "Today's Date" (GetDate) for each row returned in the select statement?

I'd like it to insert:

```
Robert    USA         9/2/15
Richard   Germany     9/2/15
Pat       USA         9/2/15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `getdate()`  and cast it to a date in your select statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country,datetransfered)
SELECT SupplierName, Country,cast(getdate() as date) FROM Suppliers;
```

**Result:**

```
+--------------+---------+----------------+
| CustomerName | Country | datetransfered |
+--------------+---------+----------------+
| Robert       | USA     | 2015-09-02     |
| Richard      | Germany | 2015-09-02     |
| Pat          | USA     | 2015-09-02     |
+--------------+---------+----------------+
```

[**SQL Server Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0df/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country, datetransfered)
SELECT SupplierName, Country, getdate() FROM Suppliers;
```

[getdate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) will insert todays date in your `datetransfered` column.

**EDIT:**

If you want to store only the date part then you need to cast it as `getdate()` return type is **datetime**.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country, datetransfered)
SELECT SupplierName, Country, cast(getdate() as date) FROM Suppliers
```

or using `Convert()`

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, Country, datetransfered)
SELECT SupplierName, Country, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) FROM Suppliers
```